# Is there any way to support USB while using Ubuntu Server with KVM kernal?

Tags: server, usb, kernel, virtualization

I'm attempting to pass through a host USB device to my Ubuntu Server VM.  The host is a Proxmox server (at home), and the VM uses an Ubuntu Server 22.04 image with cloud-init that I use to generate new VMs.  I have been unable, up to this point, to get the VM to recognize any USBs passed through to it, and I finally think I know why: The kernel associated with it is 5.15.0-1028-kvm, and I just read that KVM kernels do not support USB.

What's the simplest way for me to support USB on this VM?  I'm a little in over my head.

Comment: Have you tried something like (with your USB vendor/product numbers): udo kvm -smp cores=4,threads=2 -cpu host -m 4096 -vga virtio -usb -device qemu-xhci,id=xhci -device usb-host,bus=xhci.0,vendorid=0x0b27,productid=0x0165 myvm.img

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work with the KVM kernel, but I solved a similar issue by installing the linux-image-extra-virtual package by running:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

or

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```